# Data transfer from DynamoDB table to another DynamoDB table

Tags: python, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a table of size 15 GB in DynamoDB. Now I need to transfer some data based on timestamps ( which is in db) to another DynamoDB. What would be the most efficient option here?

a) Transfer to S3,process with pandas or someway and put in the other table (data is huge. I feel this might take a huge time)

b) Through DataPipeLine (read a lot but don't think we can put queries over there)

c) Through EMR and Hive (this seems to be the best option but is it possible to do everything though a python script? Would I need to create an EMR Cluster and use it or create and terminate every time? How can EMR be used efficiently and cheaply as well?)

Comment: 15 GB doesn't seem like a lot in DynamoDB world. If this is a one time operation and it's not time sensitive then you can simply do a full table scan and do the transfer programmatically in a few hours. You can temporarily increase throughput to accelerate the process. In any case the data pipeline will also be limited by your read throughput so will not be faster. Data pipeline is more useful if you will do this regularly

Comment: @TofigHasanov it would be on demand.... So a script which might run everyday or monthly......

Comment: @TofigHasanov full table scan would mean moving 15 GB data whereas i might need only a few mbs or GBs

Comment: Unless your timestamps are indexed and there is a way to query records you need, you will still have to do full table scan to get the records you want

Comment: Even if timestamps are sort keys, you still probably have different primary keys. As you probably know, you can't query by sort key alone: you need to specify unique primary keys, so unless all your records have same hash key you won't be able to avoid full scan

Comment: @TofigHasanov ok so isn't EMR hive faster for full scan ?i mean full scan and query processing

Comment: Not really, because it is still limited by the read throughput your table has. It doesn't matter if you read in parallel or sequentially, you still can't use more than what your throughput allows you. That being said, if your throughput is sufficiently high to make single host processing a bottleneck, you might find that EMR will allow you to process records faster

Comment: @TofigHasanov thru EMR i don't need S3 RT? I can avoid that step RT ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with the data pipeline into S3 approach. And then have a script to read from S3 and process your records. You can schedule this to run on regular intervals to backup all your data. I don't think that any solution that does a full scan will offer you a faster way, because it is always limited by read throughput.

Another possible approach is to use dynamoDB stream and lambdas to maintain second table in real time. Still you will first need to process existing 15 GB once using approach above, and then switch to lambdas for keeping them in sync